# How to delete particular data from database table by using spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have created a login page on which I have mentioned the forgot password link which redirect user to the page where they have to insert email address in order to receive the token generated from the program. With the help of this token user is redirected to change password page where he/she is able to change their password.

Now, my concern is to set the expiry time to that token which is stored in database and should get deleted after that particular time.
How can I do this by using Spring boot?

*This controller generates and save the token in database.*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgotPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String forgotPassword(HttpServletRequest request, String email) {

    Client user = clientService.getClientByEmail(email);
    if (user != null) {

        user.setConfirmationToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        clientService.updateUser(user);

        String appUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort();

        SimpleMailMessage registrationEmail = new SimpleMailMessage();
        registrationEmail.setTo(user.getEmail());
        registrationEmail.setSubject("Link Confirmation");
        registrationEmail.setText("Hi " + user.getFirstname()
                + ", To confirm your e-mail address and continue change password              , please  click to the belo link:\n"
                + appUrl + "/confirm/" + user.getConfirmationToken());
        // registrationEmail.setFrom("noreply@domain.com");

        emailService.sendEmail(registrationEmail);

        return "A confirmation e-mail has been sent to " + user.getEmail();

    } else
        return "email does not exitst with any user";
}
```

*This controller redirects the changePassword page when a token is clicked*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirm/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView confirmEmail(@PathVariable("token") String confirmationToken, Model m,Client c,Principal p) {
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
    Client user = clientService.getClientByconfirmationToken(confirmationToken);

    if (p != null) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/dashboard");
    }

    if (user != null ) {
        m.addAttribute("token",user.getConfirmationToken());
        mv.setViewName("/changePassword");
        return mv;

    } 

    else {
        mv.setViewName("redirect:/changePassword?invalidToken");
    }
        return mv;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Scheduling at your main spring boot class by using `@EnableScheduling` and schedule a job to run to delete from table after a time.

```
@Component
public class ScheduleDeleteTokenJob {

@Autowired your repo

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 60000)  /there are more you can customize your job to run like cron...
    public void deleteToken() {
    //define your logic to delete token
     }
}
```

See more here to customize your job [EnableScheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html)

See here working example guide [scheduling-tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Answer (score 0):

There are few aspects to your problem,

1. You need token expiry
2. You need to check if token has been already used by user.

Solution :

You can use [Spring Rest JWT Authentication](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) to generate expiring token which automatically expires after set time, no need to store it anywhere.

Now, as you also need to check if TOKEN has been already used, you can store the token in database as a field of that USER OBJECT.
So, every time user is redirected back to application endpoint from email, JWT will automatically check if TOKEN is valid and has not expired, and then as a next step you can also check if its the same token you saved in db before letting user reset their password.

As a last step, make sure to remove that token from DB once user successfully resets the password, as this will prevent same token from being used again for password rest within expiry time-frame.

You can tinker around this, to customize the solution as per application requirements such as if you want user to be notified if someone tried to attempt password reset using expired token or already used token.

Comment: Is there any other way to do that. This gets complexities for me.

Comment: You can also use JOB based approach to run at scheduled intervals maybe every hour to check and remove tokens from database which are past their expiry time. 
Although this approach is not encouraged for enterprise level applications, what  I have shared is enterprise level solution which takes decent time for implementation, but once implemented uses less system/database resources and can we tweaked easily.
Reference Link : https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/enable-scheduling-scheduled-job-example/